# Difference between force stop and kill process

Tags: force-stop, greenify

I used to use greenify on my rooted Xperia U. The XDA page of [Greenify](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2155737) states the difference between the task killer and greenify. Here is what the developer posted.

> Unlike any "XXX Task Killer", your device never fall into the
> cat-mouse-game of stealthy-running and aggressive killing, which
> unnecessarily consumes much battery juice. Since all greenified apps
> will be put into hibernation until the next time you launch them,
> there is no need to "kill" them during the hibernation.

I know android dont need **Task Killer App**.
I recently used Greenify on a non rooted phone in which I use hibernate shortcut to greenify app. Whenever I launch the shortcut. It will open the running apps `App Info` page and the `Force Stop` button will be automatically pressed (like an automated pearl script)

I didnt see this in my rooted phone. All I will see is Greenify had granted root permission and so and so apps are hibernated.

This confused me. Is there any difference between force stop and task kill. What is the differnce between Greenify and Task kill.

The thing about Task killer are, they kill the apps and if you are launching again the app has to start from the scratch and the task killer runs in background consuming battery. Is force stopping is similar to it? and yes Greenify do run in backfround.

Answer (score 2):

Greenify and Task killer kill your apps, *but* Greenify also disable the receiver in the greenified apps. This way the apps won't be able to start again stealthily. The pro version can act as a GCM proxy, in which GCM messages are rerouted to Greenify and it can wake a greenified apps, giving you the best of both world (no RAM and CPU usage, yet still able respon to push message) for messaging and email apps.

Comment: Does greenify do any additional task  other than force stop?Because for a unrooted phone it is just force stopping the app

Comment: @sameer with root greenify can auto-hibernate the apps without user interaction.